# android bedside alarm clock

Tags: android, alarm-clock

I once had an archos 35 home connect android alarm clock and I want sth. like that again. I know the xoro and orbsmart products, anything else? It should be the combination of a cheap android phone with speakers and a stand.

Answer (score 1):

The **Zettaly Avy** seems to be a good option, though I'm not sure if this is still in your "cheap" range.

It has a full Android tablet, pretty up-to-date with Android 6.0 (not the latest...but not that bad either) and comes with the Google Play Store.

Here [On Amazon](http://amzn.to/2DIx9tb) for **$129.99**